# fastest Java collection for string lookup?

Tags: java, collections

I have a Java class which contains two Strings, for example the name of a person and the name of the group.

I also have a list of groups (about 10) and a list of persons (about 100). The list of my data objects is larger, it can exceed 10.000 items.

Now I would like to search through my data objects such that I find all objects having a person from the person list and a group from the group list.

My question is: what is the best data structure for the person and group list?

I could use an ArrayList and simply iterate until I find a match, but that is obviously inefficient. A HashSet or HashMap would be much better.

Are there even more efficient ways to solve this? Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Every data structure has pro and cons.

A `Map` is used to retrieve data in O(1) if you have an access key.

A `List` is used to mantain an order between elements, but accessing an element using a key is not possible and you need to loop the whole list that happens in O(n).

Answer (score 1):

A good data-structure for storing and lookup strings is a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie):

It's essentially a tree structure which uses characters or substrings to denote paths to follow.

[image]

Advantages over hash-maps (quote from Wikipedia):

> - Looking up data in a trie is faster in the worst case, O(m) time (where m is the length of a search string), compared to an imperfect hash table. An imperfect hash table can have key collisions. A key collision is the hash function mapping of different keys to the same position in a hash table. The worst-case lookup speed in an imperfect hash table is O(N) time, but far more typically is O(1), with O(m) time spent evaluating the hash.
> - There are no collisions of different keys in a trie.
>     Buckets in a trie, which are analogous to hash table buckets that store key collisions, are necessary only if a single key is associated with more than one value.
> - There is no need to provide a hash function or to change hash functions as more keys are added to a trie.
> - A trie can provide an alphabetical ordering of the entries by key.

Comment: Can I quote/copy from wikipedia?

Comment: I see you discovered how to do that. So it's true that this answer is not a link-only answer anymore, and that's an improvement, but it's still a low-quality answer: You have not explained how a Trie would be a benefit for this particular problem. Note that Java hash maps have optimizations in them that reduce both hash calculation time and collision resolutions. If you claim that a trie would be more efficient, you have to show actual calculations, not a general discussion.

Comment: I agree but the question is so vague and ambiguous, that it would take a large amount to write a good answer for all the possible scenarios the OP could be in. I think I helped by pointing towards Tries. But I don't blame anyone for flagging my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Davide answer..If we want fast lookup as well as to maintain the order too, then we can go for `LinkedHashMap` implementation of Map.
By using it, we can have both things:

1. Data retrieval, If we have access key.
2. We can maintain the insertion order, so while iterating we will get the data in the same order as of during insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the scenario *(If you have the data before receiving lists of groups/people)*, preprocessing the data would save you time.

Comparing the data to the groups/people lists will require at least 10,000+ lookups. Comparing the groups/people lists to the data will require a max `10*100 = 1,000` lookups,.. less if you compare against each group one at a time (`10+100 = 110` lookups).